# wxpython thumbnail view of files windows style

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to build a code that would show the pdf files listed in a folder the way it appears in windows as thumbnails, I have an image (URL Below) that illustrates what I am trying to achieve.

https://scottiestech.info/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/unhappy_thumbnails.jpg

I understand there is the Thumbnailctrl widget that solves for this but I am trying to avoid using the widget..and to see if this can be achieved with wx.panel, wx.button etc..

I have a rough code but nothing seems to appear like the one in windows, had a tough time wrapping the text too..please help..

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(150,150))

        self.rootPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        innerPanel = wx.Panel(self.rootPanel,-1, size=(150,150), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        innerPanel.SetBackgroundColour('WHITE')
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        innerBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        buttonLabel = "Two this text was long so hence it was decided\n".center(5) + "Fox jumped over the river".center(5)
        txt = wx.StaticText(innerPanel, id=-1, label=buttonLabel,style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER, name="")
        bmp = wx.Bitmap("lion.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        button = wx.BitmapButton(innerPanel, id=wx.ID_ANY, bitmap=bmp,size=(bmp.GetWidth()+10, bmp.GetHeight()+10))
        innerBox.AddSpacer((150,75))
        innerBox.Add(txt, 0, wx.CENTER)
        innerBox.AddSpacer((150,75))
        innerPanel.SetSizer(innerBox)

        hbox.Add(innerPanel, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        vbox.Add(hbox, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)

        self.rootPanel.SetSizer(vbox)
        vbox.Fit(self)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'wxBoxSizer.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Center()
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Have you seen wxPython demos for different types of list boxes with images? Perhaps use some of them.

Comment: I did take a look at them but Is it possible to use just the listbook part for listing the files, it seems we have to have a counter panel for each listboook item clicked? Also, I took a look at 'wx.LC_ICON style' in the Ultimate List Ctrl widget and looks like this may be the closest match, but since I am new to wxPython I am not sure if this can work too..

Comment: Yes, it should. You can always inherit the listbox you choose and change it slightly to look as you want and do what you need. The principle is same as for customized dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the size of a widget with the `size=` parameter in the constructor call, then it also sets the item's minimum size.  The minimum size, if set, overrides the sizer's calculation of the best size of an item.  So the first step is to remove the 2 instances of `size=(150,150)` in your sample code.

The next issue is that you are not adding the bitmap button to the `innerBox` sizer, so the layout of the button is not managed in any way, so it overlaps the static text.

Finally, using the [Widget Inspection Tool](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool) is very helpful in debugging layout issues like this.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        self.rootPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        innerPanel = wx.Panel(self.rootPanel,-1, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        innerPanel.SetBackgroundColour('WHITE')
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        innerBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        buttonLabel = "Two this text was long so hence it was decided\n".center(5) + "Fox jumped over the river".center(5)
        txt = wx.StaticText(innerPanel, id=-1, label=buttonLabel,style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER, name="")
        bmp = wx.Bitmap("pawprints.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        button = wx.BitmapButton(innerPanel, id=wx.ID_ANY, bitmap=bmp,size=(bmp.GetWidth()+10, bmp.GetHeight()+10))
        innerBox.AddSpacer((150,75))
        innerBox.Add(txt)
        innerBox.Add(button)
        innerBox.AddSpacer((150,75))
        innerPanel.SetSizer(innerBox)

        hbox.Add(innerPanel, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        vbox.Add(hbox, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)

        self.rootPanel.SetSizer(vbox)
        vbox.Fit(self)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'wxBoxSizer.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Center()
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
import wx.lib.inspection
wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```